# Serialize type System.Drawing.Rectangle from .Net to C++ Using protobuf

Tags: c#, c++, objective-c, protobuf-net

If I Serialize (using protobuf) a rectangle (System.Drawing.Rectangle) in c#, is that possible to Deserialize it in Objective-C or C++, because System.Drawing.Rectangle is not common type like int.

If possible, what is the best way to get this rectangle in c++ or Objective-c?

Comment: I have already a bin file that contains System.Drawing.Rectangle type !

Comment: What exactly is 'this rectangle'?  Please show us your code.

Comment: The bin file already existed and contains the rectangle, is that possible to get the same rectangle in c++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fix it by using my own class type, I mean by replacing the System.Drawing.Rectangle to my own class than contains the same properties.

I mean if you want to serialize and deserialize  you have to use common types.

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Drawing.Rectangle` type is not supported directly in protobuf-net (the auto-tuple code doesn't trigger because of a few extra properties), so I'm assuming that you either have a *surrogate* in place, or you are configuring the model manually - for example:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Rectangle),false)
                .Add("X","Y","Width","Height");
```

In which case, what you need to do is to create a .proto schema that **matches that**. protobuf-net will actually help you here:

```
var proto = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.GetSchema(typeof(Rectangle));
```

which for me (i.e. for the configuration I used) generates:

```
message Rectangle {
   optional int32 X = 1;
   optional int32 Y = 2;
   optional int32 Width = 3;
   optional int32 Height = 4;
}
```

This should be usable from any protobuf implementation.